# Decomposition of conic equation for two intersecting lines

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, eigenvalues, homogeneous-spaces, conic-sections

By using homogeneous coordinates ${\bf x}=[x, y, 1]^T$, a conic section can be expressed by ${\bf x}^T {\bf C} {\bf x} = 0$ with ${\bf C}$ being a 3x3 symmetric matrix. A degenerate form of the conic section is the type "two intersecting lines". When the two lines are also given in homogeneous coordinates with ${\bf g}^T {\bf x}=0$ and ${\bf h}^T {\bf x}=0$, the conic is computed as
    $${\bf C} = {\bf g} {\bf h}^T + {\bf h} {\bf g}^T$$

How do I extract ${\bf g}$ and ${\bf h}$ from ${\bf C}$?

Interestingly, there seems to be a nice solution for the problem which I found in  [this](http://people.cas.uab.edu/~mosya/cl/AtoG.m) Matlab script - however, without any proof. The conic matrix is decomposed using eigendecomposition with
$$ {\bf C} = {\bf Q} {\bf \Lambda} {\bf Q}^-1$$
After that, the minimum and maximum eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, multiplied with the corresponding eigenvectors ${\bf q}_{\text{min}}$ and ${\bf q}_{\text{max}}$ give
$${\bf q}_{\text{min}}'=\sqrt{|\lambda_{\text{min}}|} {\bf q}_{\text{min}} $$
$${\bf q}_{\text{max}}'=\sqrt{|\lambda_{\text{max}}|} {\bf q}_{\text{max}} $$
Scaled (and possibly interchanged) versions of ${\bf g}$ and ${\bf h}$ can then be computed with
$${\bf g}' = {\bf q}_{\text{min}}' + {\bf q}_{\text{max}}'$$
$${\bf h}' = {\bf q}_{\text{min}}' - {\bf q}_{\text{max}}'$$

Has someone an idea how to derive or proof the solution?